# Show there exist a unit vector $v$ such that $L$ is defined by the matrix $v v^T$. Conclude $L$ is the orthogonal projection on $S=Span(v)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear operator $L: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is called a *projection* if $L^2 = L$. A projection $L$ is an *orthogonal projection* if $\ker L$ is orthogonal to $L(\mathbb R^n)$.

I've shown that the only invertible projection is the identity map $I_{\mathbb R^n}$ by using function composition on the identity $L^2(v) = L$.

**Question:**
Now suppose that $L$ is an orthogonal projection whose image $L(\mathbb R^n)$ has rank $1$. Show there exist a unit vector $v$ such that $L$ is defined by the matrix $v v^T$. Conclude $L$ is the orthogonal projection on $S=Span(v)$.

I know I can write the orthogonal projection $P_S: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow S$ as $u u^T$ using an orthonormal basis $\{u\}$ for $S$. And since $v$ is a unit vector, $\{v\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $S$, so $P_S = vv^T$. So the only thing to show is that there exist such a vector $v$ with the stated property ?

Comment: Yup pretty much, and there is not many candidates for $v$ anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you mean ? Do you have any suggestions on how to prove this ? :)

Comment: How do I decide the $\ker L$ for $L$ ?