# Show matrix representation for $L$ with respect to the standard basis is $I−\frac 2 {\|v\|^2}vv^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ of dimension $1$.

Now suppose $\{v\}$ is a basis for $S$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1}\}$ is a basis for $\bar S$.

I know $\dim \bar S = m-1$ and $\{v, v_1, \ldots, v_{m-1}\} $ is a basis for $\mathbb R^m$.

Let $L: \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ satisfying $L(v)=-v$ and $L(v_i) = v_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, m-1$ be a linear transformation.

How do I show that the matrix representation for $L$ with respect to the standard basis is $I−\dfrac 2 {\|v\|^2}vv^T$ ? I've tried computing it the usual way, but it is impossible to determine $L(e_i)$ for $1,\ldots, m$.

Comment: What is $\bar S$? Orthogonal complement? Any complement?

Comment: Orthogonal complement of $S$.

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

$$\forall k=1,\ldots,m-1,\quad L(v_k)=v_k-\frac 2 {||v||^2}vv^Tv_k=v_k-\frac 2 {||v||^2}v\langle v,v_k\rangle=v_k$$
and
$$L(v)=v-\frac 2 {||v||^2}vv^Tv=v-\frac 2 {||v||^2}v\langle v,v\rangle=-v$$

Comment: Thank you Sami. I appreciate your answer. Would you mind comment if you have any ideas on solving this ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739487/show-there-exist-a-unit-vector-v-such-that-l-is-defined-by-the-matrix-v-vt ? It is a freind of mine who asked the question, who asked me for help first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by standard basis, but it is certainly true that for 
$A=I - 2 vv^T /\|v\|^2$, $Av=-v$ and $Av_i=v_i$ if $v$ is orthogonal to the $v_i$'s specified.

Hence

$$L(e_i)=A e_i = e_i - v v_{(i)} / \|v\|^2,$$

where $v_{(i)}$ is the $i$-th element of the vector $v$.

Comment: Thanks ! However you need a factor of $-2$ in $L(e_i)$ ?